# How do you launch IE in IE compatibility mode when using watir-webdriver?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, ie8-compatibility-mode

I know it is possible to change the default download directory, etc. by passing in a hash of options to Google or Firefox or, here, Internet Explorer.

Is there a way to launch IE in compatibility mode by default?

Comment: The current recommendation is to us watir gem vs. the watir-webriver gem, since it has better IE support.

Are you using watir gem or watir-webdriver gem?

Comment: Given that watir gem has better IE support, I would strongly advise using it. This advise is for IE. For other browsers use watir-webdriver.

Comment: See https://github.com/watir/watir

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  do you expect your users to be running in compatibility mode?   There are a number of documented things that don't work the same between the real thing and later IE versions in compatibility mode.  So if your objective is to see how well the site or web-app works with an older obsolete version of IE, like IE8, then you'd be better off to create an XP VM with IE8 and run your tests on it to actually test the real thing, not a emulation.

Comment: the question is just as much about passing options into IE as it is this specific feature. Firefox and Chrome have much more documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the watir gem, you will find that it offers a [class Watir::IE](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/1.6.2/classes/Watir/IE.html).

The Watir::IE class provides a [set_options(options) method](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/1.6.2/classes/Watir/IE.html#M000210), which will allow you to specify the options to be used when creating a new Watir::IE instance.

I don't have a handle on the exact options to pass, buit I will continue to research. If I find it, I will edit this answer. If someone else knows, hopefully, they will edit this answer with the details.

Comment: The links above point to an older version of watir.  This is the current rdoc: http://rubydoc.info/github/watir/watir-classic/frames